# C# 'Default1': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm getting this error and sure how to fix it, I'm trying to create a loader class that inherits from the Default1, then to use its in the method.

```
namespace MyLevel
{
    class Default1
    {
        public interface Default1
        {
            IEnumerable<DefaultCore> GetDefaultValues();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused here about how to define and/or implement interfaces.

What you have there is a class, named `Default1`, which is defining an internal, nested interface named `Default1`. There are three problems with this:

1. You can't do that; the names cannot be the same because it creates possible ambiguity with the names. The error message was pretty clear here. (As others have stated, interfaces are usually called `ISomething`, which resolves the name conflict.
2. That interface is defined in a strange way; it is nested inside an internal (thanks @FishBasketGordo for reminding me!) class. That means it's only visible inside the assembly where you defined it, and it has to be referenced as `Default1.IDefault` (assuming you fixed the name).
3. Nothing is actually implementing your interface, so it is not being used anywhere.

If you want to define an interface, you don't need a class:

```
namespace MyLevel
{
    public interface IDefault
    {
        IEnumerable<DefaultCore> GetDefaultValues();
    }
}
```

If you want your class to implement that interface:

```
namespace MyLevel
{
    public class Default1 : IDefault
    {
        public IEnumerable<DefaultCore> GetDefaultValues() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the interface is public, and the class (by default) is internal, the interface isn't completely useless. Other classes within the same assembly could use it, but I agree, it's a little weird to define an interface within a class.

Comment: true, for some reason I *still* keep thinking that classes default to `private` and have to correct myself mentally. I will edit your comments into the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I had to look it up myself, but if you think about it, a private class at the namespace level doesn't make much sense, and having classes that default to public wouldn't jive with the general explicitness everywhere else in C#.

Comment: yeah, it makes perfect sense why C# is the way it is, and why you can't have private top-level classes, I just mentally associated "no access modifier" with "private" almost reflexively...

Answer (score 1):

Because you've defined the interface within the class, it is a member of the class, and a class cannot have two members with the same name nor can it have a member with the same name as the class itself. That's what the error message is saying.

Thus, change the name of either `Default1` (the class) or `Default1` (the interface).

Most interfaces are prefixed with a capital `I` by convention, so `IDefault1` would be a good choice for the interface. Also, unrelatedly, why are you defining an interface within a class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the class to inherit the interface, it needs to be outside of the class. Secondly, utilize standard naming conventions and prefix the interface name with an `I` ( e.g. `IDefault`, `ICloneable`, `IDisposable`, etc.):

```
namespace MyLevel
{
    public class Default : IDefault
    {

    }

    public interface IDefault
    {
        IEnumerable<DefaultCore> GetDefaultValues();            
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks am trying to inherit  from DefaultCore, at the moment am getting error saying (Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ThisLevel.DefaultCore>' is less accessible than method 'ThisLevel.IDefault.GetDefaultValue()'

Comment: Check the access modifier for the `DefaultCore` class, and make sure it's as accessible as the interface.

Comment: For the purposes of testing, see if using `IEnumerable<int>` will compile. If it does, you know that the problem is with `DefaultCore`. Also, make sure that you're importing the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not evaluate.

Interface is (of normal) to start with the I

not requirement for the build, yet common as the LAW

just go IDefault !

PRASHANT :)

Comment: While I don't personally think this is deserving of a downvote, it lacks any backing or explanation. Here is a [link to the microsoft naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx) backing your statement. `Do prefix interface names with the letter I to indicate that the type is an interface.`

Comment: @prashantp I downvoted because your answer doesn't _help_ the OP in context of the question, I feel it addresses another issue - also, it's rather poorly worded. Clean up and I'd be happy to upvote you :)